# Generate API Docs with OpenAPI Maven plugin

Tags: spring, maven, swagger, openapi

I am trying to generate API docs endpoint (e.g. `/v3/api-docs`) for a Spring REST application generated from an OpenAPI 3 yaml.

I noticed that the [Maven plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin) has a `generateApiDocumentation` flag, though 
I'm not exactly sure what it does.

Unfortunately [SpringFox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox) doesn't support OpenAPI 3 yet -- and also it would seem pointless to have a reflection based generator when all I want to do is expose the initial yaml as a json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if a understand your question, but can try check this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

Also you can check the documentation https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi

Basically you just have to add this maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.32</version>
</dependency>
```

After that, when you start your service you can check your host with the path: /swagger-ui.html in this form:

```
http//localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

I expect I would help you.

Answer (score 0):

https://springdoc.org/faq.html

What is a proper way to set up Swagger UI to use provided spec.yml?

With this property, all the springdoc-openapi auto configuration beans are disabled:

```
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
```

Then enable the minimal beans configuration, by adding this Bean:

```
@Bean
SpringDocConfiguration springDocConfiguration(){
   return new SpringDocConfiguration();
}
@Bean
public SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties() {
   return new SpringDocConfigProperties();
}
```

Then configure, the path of your custom UI yaml file.

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/my-api-docs.yaml
```

In this case, you should place ***'my-api-docs.yaml'*** into ***'src/main/resources/static/'*** folder!